# 32 and 64 Bit versions (other depedencies) with build lifecycle in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven for a while to build my applications.

In the depedencies of my pom.xml file I have something like that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>MyLib32Bit</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLib32Bit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!--
<dependency>
    <groupId>MyLib64Bit</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLib64Bit</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
-->
```

When I want to build a 32-Bit version of my program I have it like above, if I want to build the 64 Bit version vice versa.. I build it usually by invoking `mvn package`

Now i want you to ask how to solve this problem in a better and nicer way... Are there any opportunities to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this is to have an artifact with both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs in them. An example of this is the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) library which have many builds in the same JAR.  It finds, extracts and uses the version for the system you are running on.  Here is a list of platforms this one jar supports is [jna/lib](https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/master/lib/native)

This code you might be useful to you [NativeLibrary](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.java)